"Ka no taikoku shin" = China? [Rurouni Kenshin Live Action]
The Rurouni Kenshin Live Action movie (2012) is set in 1878 Tokyo Japan. In it, a high-ranking general (Yamagata) talks about how opium (アヘン) (which is spreading through japan) might destroy Japan as it did China. Specifically, after presenting the opium, he says "アヘンは国｛くに｝を滅｛ほろ｝ぼす。kaの大国｛たいこく｝shinでさえアヘンを止｛と｝められず、土地｛とち｝の一部｛いちぶ｝がイギリスの植民地｛しょくみんち｝となった。" The subtitles translate this as "Opium will destroy a country. A land as powerful as China couldn't control it. Now part of the country is an English colony."
My question is only about the "kaの大国｛たいこく｝shin". How does that refer to China (or powerful)? In particular, the "ka" and the "shin" are the parts I don't understand.

Is this your own transcription or does it come from subtitles?

The か is almost definitely 華, as in 中華, 華人 or 華夏.  Not too sure about the しん, but I'm wondering it could be 死んで. Aka 華の大国死んでさえアヘンを止められず. "The grand country of China could not stop opium until its death (or even by dying)"

@KarlKnechtel The transcription is from me, but I'm 99% sure of it. His speech is extremely clear and precise. I'll have a clip uploaded later if needed.
@ dvx2718 that's an interesting interpretation, but I have a feeling it's wrong. Calling China "dead" like that (in the context of the conversation with someone who doesn't know international politics) seems wrong.

@chausies Honestly, the last dynasty of China 清 officially collapsed in 1912, and before that (in 1878 like you say the film is based on), it was barely hanging by the last thread. Anyone with foresights in that period would not think of China as the powerhouse it used to be, but clearly a country on its deathbed. For more contexts, China would later lose to Japan in the 日清戦争 in 1894, and Beijing would fall under the 八か国連合軍 which included Japan in 1900 (The empress 慈禧 fled but a treaty was later signed for her to come back to the capital)

@dvx2718 華 is a kanji meaning China but it's not a word meaning China.


かの is this 彼の. It is basically an older form of あの, but is now often used to add a nuance of "あの有名な" or "that famous ～". This is where "as powerful as" came from.
[しん]{HL} is how Japanese people pronounce Qing (清) (1644-1912).


かの大国、清でさえ
even that famous dynasty, Qing


Maybe it's just me that finds it odd to refer to the country as Qing. It would be like calling the US as "Obama" or "Washington". But I guess that's how they did it.

@chausies They did the same in Chinese too, and it’s no coincidence, I think, that the words immediately preceding 清 are 大国 – a common Chinese term for China in the Qing Dynasty was 大清国. It’s not really anything like calling the US ‘Obama’ or ‘Washington’; those are people who were presidents at some point, whereas Qing was the name of the empire as a whole, not its ruler. According to Google, there are parallel uses of 明治國 in Japanese as well. (Plus there are countries named after rulers, e.g., the Philippines, Bolivia, Peru – and of course Washington state, though it’s not a country.)

@chausies There is no single "China" that existed for thousands of years. China is a collective term to refer to many countries that ruled that area. The dynasties in China have been destroyed many times, and essentially a different "country" has started each time. The Qing is one of such countries, and Qing itself is not someone's personal name.
